# BULK INSERT not performing well

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bulkinsert, bcp

In my scenario I need to write 100 million rows from various files of different size to SQL server from a remote machine (in the same network). To get better performance I am already writing the data files in CSV format to the a disk of my SQL machine (Y:).
This is an extract of one of the files I am trying to import

```
786,166537,46,928024944,23224244.87759578,0.00000021
785,166537,46,923850272,15364.87759500,0.00100000
...
```

And this is MyTable

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BigNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DecimalNumber] [decimal](26, 8) NOT NULL,
    [NullableDecimal] [decimal](26, 8) NULL
)
```

Note: `NullableDecimal` is nullable but it is always defined as 0.0 when empty. Also, there are no index on the table.

After the file has been moved to the SQL server I call this procedure passing the full paths of the CSV file and the format file:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_bulk_insert
@bcp_file AS NVARCHAR(200),
@format_file AS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT dbo.MyTable 
            FROM''' + @bcp_file + ''' 
            WITH 
          (
            FORMATFILE = ''' + @format_file + ''',
            TABLOCK
          );';
    EXEC(@sql);
END

EXEC usp_bulk_insert @bcp_file='Y:\bcp\test.csv', @format_file='Y:\fmt\format_file.xml'
```

I have also defined an XML format file to help

```
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="21"/>>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="41"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="41"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Id" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Number1" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Number2" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="BigNumber" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="DecimalNumber" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="26" SCALE="8"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="NullableDecimal" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="26" SCALE="8"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

No matter what I try I don't seem to be able to do better than 30 seconds for a 300Mb file with 3 million rows.

I tried a few tips from this [website](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/making-most-bcp-seven-tips-speeding-large-data-loads-bulk-copy-program); it is recommended to use local named pipes, I tried and I could not find too much information about it. 
Is there anything I can try to do better?

---------- EDIT

I run the `BULK INSERT` command in a new session and run the command

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats order by wait_time_ms desc
```

Here the top 10 results:

```
session_id  wait_type   waiting_tasks_count wait_time_ms
75  SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 7107    206
75  MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT   38934   111
75  PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILE 528 65
75  IMPPROV_IOWAIT  6   44
75  PAGEIOLATCH_EX  2   20
75  PREEMPTIVE_OS_CREATEFILE    10  7
75  WRITELOG    1   3
75  PREEMPTIVE_OS_FILEOPS   4   2
75  PAGEIOLATCH_UP  1   1
```

I will investigate on those!

---------- EDIT

I have full control of the creation of the file, what I cannot change is the format of the final table

[image: Remote Scan]
[image: Table Insert]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212675/discussion-on-question-by-abx78-bulk-insert-not-performing-well).